# Using result of one function as a variable in another - node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, jwt

I'm writing a node.js script to generate a GitHub installation access token. Here's what I've got:

```
const axios = require("axios");
var fs = require('fs');
var jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

var gitInstallationAccessToken = {
  genJWTToken: function(callback) {
    var private_key = fs.readFileSync("/path/to/my/pemfile.pem");

  const now = Math.round(Date.now() / 1000);
  const payload = {
    iat : now,
    exp : now + (10 * 60),
    iss : 7233
  };

  const token = jwt.sign(payload, private_key, { algorithm: 'RS256' })
  callback(token);
  },

  genInstallationAccessToken: function(token, callback) {
    var jwt = gitInstallationAccessToken.genJWTToken(function(token) {
      return token;
    });
    console.log("JWT: ", jwt)
    var instance = axios({
      method: "post",
      url: "https://api.github.com/installations/:installation_id/access_tokens",
      headers: {
        "Accept" : "application/vnd.github.machine-man-preview+json",
        "Authorization" : `Bearer ${jwt}`
      }
    })
    .then(function(response) {
      console.log("Response: ",response.data);
      callback(response);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.warn("Unable to authenticate");
      // The request was made and the server responded with a status code
      // that falls out of the range of 2xx
      if (error.response) {
        console.warn(`Status ${error.response.status}`);
        console.warn(`${error.response.data.message}`);
      }
    });
  }
}

module.exports = gitInstallationAccessToken;

gitInstallationAccessToken.genInstallationAccessToken(function(response) {
  console.log("response: ", response)
});
```

My JWT token is getting generated by `genJWTToken`. I can see that if I add a `console.log("Token: ", token)` before the callback in `genJWTToken`.

I now need to use that token in `genInstallationAccessToken` but I'm clearly calling it wrong. As the following returns undefined:

```
var jwt = gitInstallationAccessToken.genJWTToken(function(token) {
  return token;
});
console.log("JWT: ", jwt)
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should consider refactoring this and use chained promises it will be easier to understand and control..

Something like this:

```js
function getToken() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    resolve('token')
  })
}


function chainPromise() {
 var token
  getToken().then((response) => {
   token = response
    console.log(token)
  }).then(() => {
   console.log('I am here and also see: ', token)
  })
}

chainPromise()
```

You should then be able to track down the path of your token quite easily

Comment: Thanks, I had to do a little reading to understand promises but sorted now.